# get the value of a list in hashmap in java (not in a sequential manner)

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have an issue regarding getting the value of a hashmap in this form  `<String, List<time,value>>`. If I want to simplify my problem the data structure is in the following format:

`{data1=[fetchTime=123, value=1], [fetchTime=124, value=8], [fetchTime=125,value=0], 
data2=[fetchTime=123, value=3], [fetchTime=124, value=8], [fetchTime=125, value=6], data3=[fetchTime=123, value=6], [fetchTime=124, value=9], [fetchTime=125, value=1]}`

What I want to do is to calculate the sum of the values of the "same" fetch time. so basically I want to sum up the values of the fetch time of 123 which is (1+3+6) and for fetch time of 124 (8+8+9) and so on.

At this point I just care about the algorithm or any hint not the exact running code,  so please suggest me how to do that.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say "not in a sequential manner"? Are no loops allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple solution, you could use another hashmap: 
ie. `resultMap<fetchTime, [long]sum>` :)

```
for each item in hashmap
  //+ extra for for each item of your list 
  if (resultMap.contains(item.fetchTime))
     resultMap.put(item.fetchTime, item.value + resultMap.get(item.value))
  else
     resultMap.put(item.fetchTime, item.value)

for each item in resultMap
  ... print keys and values
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but how would I make sure that the value of matching fetch time are summing up? what does (resultMap.contains(item.fetchTime)) do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I meant to say containsKey. it is a method from hashmap. it will return true if a key exists. If it exists, you get the stored value for that key and add the value of the current item, and then store this new value to that key

Comment: One thing else which I have doubt is that is resultMap initiated from the first place? how would resultMap.contains(item.fetchTime) be if I just define it without value from the first place?

Comment: when resultMap does not have a value, you simply add it, as on the else case resultMap.put(item.fetchTime, item.value). You should do a check on item.value for a valid value if that can be an issue.